# Yii 2 ajax form submission how to get error to respective input as I received response in json

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am getting response in Json for my model rules but How do i suppose to map that to input which is on view file...

Kindly help

**Controller**

```
public function actionUpdateprofile(){
    $model= new User;
    $model->scenario = 'updateprofile';

     if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $model->validate();
   // return $this->render('index',['model'=>$model]);
if($model->hasErrors()) {   
       Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
         }   else      return 'success';

    }



}
```

**View**

```
$('form#edit-profile-form').on('beforeSubmit', function (e) {
// send data to actionSave by ajax request.

$.post($(this).attr('action'),$(this).serialize()).done( function(response){ 

} ).fail();


return false; // Cancel form submitting.});
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to have `2.0.6` version, as this was not possible before `Yii 2.0.6`. Here is the example usage code:

```
// add error for single attribute
$('#contact-form').yiiActiveForm('updateAttribute', 'contactform-subject', ["I have an error..."]);

// remove error from single attribute
$('#contact-form').yiiActiveForm('updateAttribute', 'contactform-subject', '');

// Or update the whole form and, optionally, summary at once:
$('#contact-form').yiiActiveForm('updateMessages', {
    'contactform-subject': ['Really?'],
    'contactform-email': ['I don\'t like it!']
}, true);
```

I took above snippet from Yii framework release [page](http://www.yiiframework.com/news/88/yii-2-0-6-is-released/)